# how to use .removeClass properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var increment = 0;

$("#dial-save").click(function(){
$(".add-flow").html("");
$(".add-flow").append("<button type='button' class='btn btn-w-s btn-ivr'><i class='fa fa-hand-o-down p-xxs' aria-hidden='true'></i>Dial</button>");

    switch(increment) {
        case 0:
                $(".flow-preview").append("<div class='col-md-1'></div><div  class='col-md-1'></div><div class='col-md-10 add-flow'><button type='button' class='btn add-applet' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModalAddApplet'>Add Applet</button></div>");
                increment++;
                $("#myModalAppletDial").modal('hide');
                $( ".add-flow:first-child" ).removeClass("add-flow");
                break;

         case 1:
                $(".flow-preview").append("<div class='col-md-1'></div><div class='col-md-1'></div><div class='col-md-1'></div><div class='col-md-9 add-flow'><button type='button' class='btn add-applet' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModalAddApplet'>Add Applet</button></div>");
                increment++;
                $("#myModalAppletDial").modal('hide');
                break;

    };

});
```

I need help on changing the line `$( ".add-flow:first-child" ).removeClass("add-flow");`. What I am trying to do here is remove `add-flow` from all tags except for the one I am appending...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
switch(increment) {
            case 0:
            $('.flow-preview').find( ".add-flow" ).removeClass("add-flow");
            $(".flow-preview").append("<div class='col-md-1'></div><div class='col-md-1'></div><div class='col-md-10 add-flow'><button type='button' class='btn add-applet' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModalAddApplet'>Add Applet</button></div>");
            increment++;
            $("#myModalAppletDial").modal('hide');
            break;

            case 1:
            $(".flow-preview").append("<div class='col-md-1'></div><div class='col-md-1'></div><div class='col-md-1'></div><div class='col-md-9 add-flow'><button type='button' class='btn add-applet' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModalAddApplet'>Add Applet</button></div>");
            increment++;
            $("#myModalAppletDial").modal('hide');
            break;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you use **:first-child** wrong. As the documentation said, :first-child will selects all elements that are the first child of their parent (https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/). How if you have several .add-flow and they are not the first child of thier parent?

I think the easies way to achive this:

1. first, you remove .add-flow from all tags
2. then, append the new one

In your code, **removeClass()** first then **append()**:

```
$( ".add-flow" ).removeClass("add-flow"); // remove first, probably you dont need :first-child here
$(".flow-preview").append("<div class='col-md-1'></div><div  class='col-md-1'></div><div class='col-md-10 add-flow'><button type='button' class='btn add-applet' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModalAddApplet'>Add Applet</button></div>"); // then append
increment++;
$("#myModalAppletDial").modal('hide');
```